# SQL Server : select attribute from xml where attribute name is defined by namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I couldnt find anything specifically on this, but I would like to know how I can select an attribute of a sub-node in XML that is identified by a namespace, asp per the XLINK namespace below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <people lastUpdateDate="xxxx-xx-xx">
    <person name="Paul" surname="Who Cares" height="180" weight="89" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgYU.jpg?s=48&g=1" />
  </people>
</result>
```

Currently my query looks like this, but I just need a small alteration in order to get the link.

```
DECLARE @xml AS TABLE(MyXml xml);

INSERT @xml SELECT CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) 
FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk '[filepath]', SINGLE_BLOB) [rowsetresults];

WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' AS a)
SELECT
      Person.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
      Person.value('@surname', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
      Person.value('@height', 'INT'),
      Person.value('@weight', 'INT'),
      Person.value('@xlink:href', 'NVARCHAR(500)'), -- THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
FROM
    @xml
    CROSS APPLY [MyXml].nodes('result/people')    AS MyXml(People)
    OUTER APPLY People.nodes('person')              AS People(Person);
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: At this point I am getting values but just NULL for the "Person.value('@xlink:href', 'NVARCHAR(500)')" section

Comment: Try replacing the colon':' from your xml with any other character.

Comment: Good idea, and that works, I will go with it! Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to replace the colon character. Just check the answer below. It shows how to handle XML namespaces correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the xlink:href with xlinkhref

```
DECLARE @xml AS TABLE(MyXml xml);

INSERT into @xml values('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <people lastUpdateDate="xxxx-xx-xx">
    <person name="Paul" surname="Who Cares" height="180" weight="89" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgYU.jpg?s=48&amp;g=1" />
  </people>
</result>')

UPDATE @xml set MyXml=REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),(MyXml)),'xlink:href','xlinkhref')

SELECT
      Person.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
      Person.value('@surname', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
      Person.value('@height', 'INT'),
      Person.value('@weight', 'INT'),
      Person.value('@xlinkhref', 'NVARCHAR(500)') -- THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
FROM
    @xml
    CROSS APPLY [MyXml].nodes('result/people')    AS MyXml(People)
    OUTER APPLY People.nodes('person')              AS People(Person);
```

Comment: Mark it as answer it that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Few points to mention. (1) The link has an ampersand. A single & is illegal in an XML except CDATA section. So I replaced it with the `&amp;`, aka ampersand entity, to make the XML well-formed. (2) The XML has a couple of namespaces, so you need to specify them in the *T-SQL*. Just one namespace is needed in this case. (3) No need to use multiple `CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY` clauses.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <people lastUpdateDate="xxxx-xx-xx">
        <person name="Paul" surname="Who Cares" height="180" weight="89"
                xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgYU.jpg?s=48&amp;g=1"/>
    </people>
</result>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' AS xlink)
SELECT c.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Name]
    , c.value('@surname', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Surname]
    , c.value('@height', 'INT') AS [Height]
    , c.value('@weight', 'INT') AS [Weight]
    , c.value('@xlink:href', 'NVARCHAR(500)') AS [URL]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/result/people/person') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| Name |  Surname  | Height | Weight |                     URL                      |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| Paul | Who Cares |    180 |     89 | https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgYU.jpg?s=48&g=1 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```